# What models are there for neuronal sequence memory?

Tags: computational-modeling

This paper https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fncir.2016.00023/full proposes a neuronal model to learn time-based sequences, referred to as HTM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_temporal_memory). An implementation is here: https://numenta.org/.

Are there any other models known or proposed?